# Querying csv with raw_input in Python

Tags: python, csv, raw-input

I'm new to programming but I decided to take on python.

I have this csv file about logged hours by users that looks roughly like this (but containing around 200 rows):

> User,Project,Hours
>   User1,ProjectA,5
>   User1,ProjectB,10
>   User2,ProjectA,7
>   User2,ProjectB,12`

I'd like to extract data from it, through several raw_inputs that would be dependant on the previous. Eg. I would start by asking if you'd want to see the full list, if yes print everything and close there. If answer is no, then move on to next raw_input, eg. Enter which user you'd like to see.

I've some code, but I know it's still really basic, but as I'm a newbie to this, I haven't been able to figure out a solution. Help is appreciated..

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("loggedhours.csv", "rb"))
Team = raw_input("Do you want to see detailed team numbers? Y/N: ")

if Team =="y":
    for User, Project, Hours in reader:
        print User, Project, Hours

else:
    print "ok"
    print ""

User = raw_input("Enter user ID you wish to check: ")

if User == User in reader:
    for User, Project, Hours in reader:
        print User
else:
    print "ok"
```

There's obviously some line missing just before the second raw_input, that will make the program finish.

But also on the first part I'm getting the right results when answer == y, but I don't get the right thing when answer != y. The `else` part is not functioning.

It's obvious there are mistakes there, but if you could direct me to the right path I would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you give us the exact output that you are getting then? Is it just not printing the 'ok' part of the else at all?

Comment: it prints all the results, so I was trying to understand why the 'else' part was not being considered.

Answer (score 2):

You could build a dict from the rows of the csv.

```
teams = {}
reader = csv.reader(open("loggedhours.csv", "rb"))
for team in reader:
    teams[team[0]] = (team[1], team[2])

def print_teamnumbers():
    for user in teams:
        print "%s: %s" % (user, teams[user])

def specific_lookup(user_id):
    print teams.get(user_id, "User not found")
```

Answer (score 2):

Jakob's answer is a good read. In answer to "mistakes":

```
if User == User in reader
```

This is obviously wrong. The `User == User` is `True`, which isn't likely to be in the `reader` object.

If you want to print an empty line, in stead of using `print ""`, just use this:

```
print
```

Also, every time you use caps for your a variable name, a kitten dies somewhere. Please read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and save the kittens.

Comment: Gotta love the kittens <3 +1 to you sir

Comment: I must have killed a few kittens by now with all the playing around with code. Thanks for the tips everyone, I'll be testing this later on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit a python program use `sys.exit`: [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.exit#sys.exit)